# Pages PrintOut Word VBS

Tags: printing, vbscript, ms-word

I can't seem to get Words `PrintOut` to accept/honor the parameter for `PAGES` when run in VBScript. Weirdly, it honors `COPIES` just fine. Any ideas?

Code:

```
Dim ObjWord
Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
ObjWord.Visible = True

'Open Document
Dim ObjDoc
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open
'.Open (FileName, ConfirmConversions, ReadOnly, AddToRecentFiles, PasswordDocument, PasswordTemplate, Revert, WritePasswordDocument, WritePasswordTemplate, Format, Encoding, Visible, OpenConflictDocument, OpenAndRepair, DocumentDirection, NoEncodingDialog)
Set ObjDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open("C:\tmp\test.docx", ,TRUE, , , , , , , , ,TRUE)  
       
'PageRange
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.printout
'.PrintOut (Background, Append, Range, OutputFileName, From, To, Item, Copies, Pages, PageType, PrintToFile, Collate, FileName, ActivePrinterMacGX, ManualDuplexPrint, PrintZoomColumn, PrintZoomRow, PrintZoomPaperWidth, PrintZoomPaperHeight)  
Dim ObjPrint
ObjPrint = ObjDoc.PrintOut(FALSE, , , , , , , ,"1", , ,TRUE)   ' No Error, but Pages not honored
'ObjPrint = ObjDoc.PrintOut(FALSE, , , , , , ,"2", , , ,TRUE)    ' Corretly Printes Two Copies
      
objDoc.Saved = TRUE
objWord.Quit

Set ObjDoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
```

Comment: As stated in your previous questions, read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout).

Comment: It's not biased, the question has been answered years ago. The fact you're using the same thing in VBScript is irrelevant and is just repeating old topics, you want to add value add the answer to the existing question and maybe even add the [tag:vbscript] tag as well.

Comment: It is RUDE to say `As stated in your previous questions`. I did read the documentation, I did search SO for related topics. The linked duplicate has a horrible title and is tagged `VBA` and `MS-WORD-2010` neither of which I am using. You don't see me complain that mods didn't update the tags to be more relevant. Ironically, I have tagged some of my `VBScript` posts w/ `VBA` and had mods remove it. Why are you pushing people away from SO??

Comment: Tags age, that doesn't mean the information is any less relevant.

Comment: My intention is not to push you away, just trying to maintain what we have without oodles of duplicates. A lot of your questions are self answered, which is fine but make sure you are not going over old ground with them.

Answer (score -1):

So I had to pass an additional param for it to honour the `Pages` value which was `Range`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout
https://documentation.help/MS-Office-Word-VB/womthPrintOut1.htm

It required a `CONSTANT` declaration. Eg:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdprintoutrange

Specifies a range to print.

```
WDPRINTOUTRANGE ENUMERATION (WORD)
Name              Value Description
wdPrintAllDocument  0   The entire document.
wdPrintCurrentPage  2   The current page.
wdPrintFromTo       3   A specified range.
wdPrintRangeOfPages 4   A specified range of pages.
wdPrintSelection    1   The current selection.
```

In my case, I believe it will always be 4.

Therefore this worked as expected. (Print Only Page 2)

```
ObjPrint = ObjDoc.PrintOut(FALSE, ,"4", , , , , ,"2", , ,TRUE)
```

Further Reading on Printing Word via VBScript. Disclaimer: This is my personal blog --> https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Print+Microsoft+Word+via+Batch+-+WINWORD.EXE+Switches+-+VBScript+Print+Specific+Pages

Comment: If it required constant declaration, why are you not using them in the code sample? Also, `PrintOut()` method doesn't return an object so `ObjPrint` is completely unnecessary, plus if it was an object reference you would expect `Set ObjPrint = ...`.

Comment: Incorrect information? What does `ObjPrint` return?, because I guarantee it isn't an object reference. Where are your declared constants in the code sample?

Comment: Try using it without `VAR = PrintOut` and VB complains `Can't Call Sub w/ Parantheses`. Try with `SET` and it doesn't work! I may not know exactly the terms, but I do post an MVCE and EXPECT users to try before rudely and incorrectly stating code is `completely unnecessary`

Comment: If you see in my full code example, I post the entire positional array of arguments and since my answer will always utilize `4` or `wdPrintRangeOfPages` I don't feel the extra line of code is worth the value. Basically, when it's something that doesn't change I tend to use the `Enumeration` vs declaring a constant and using that, but there is definite debate on best practices for that which I may regret/be wrong by not using the "extra code" for readability in this case.

Comment: In which case you either 1. Remove the brackets and it will work `ObjDoc.PrintOut False, , "4", , , , , , "2", , , True` or 2. use `Call ObjDoc.PrintOut(False, , "4", , , , , , "2", , ,True)`. Either of those will work.